# Having Trouble With Internet Explorer Session Launching on my Protractor Tests

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, protractor, config

I'm trying to launch my automation tests on Internet explorer but they are not working. In my console it sounds like selenium is running correctly but then it is unable to create a session.

```
[09:32:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:32:10] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[09:32:11] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.30.2.118:60727/wd/hub
[09:32:15] E/launcher - Unable to create session from {
"desiredCapabilities": {
    "count": 1,
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "version": "11",
    "platform": "ANY"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "internet explorer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've made sure all of the protected mode security settings are unchecked in IE.
All of my drivers are up to date

```
//protractor.conf 
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  capabilities: {
    //  'seleniumAddress': 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'version': '11'
  },
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  params: {
    login: {
      user: 'user123',
      password: 'Pass123'
    },
    url: {
      site: 'https://website.com'
    }
  },
  //directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000,
    print: function () { }
  },
```

I'm expecting the launch of IE when i run my code. Chrome works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve this issue you have to do two things :**

1. You will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.
2. Change few settings of Internet Explorer browser on that machine (**where you desire to run automation**).

**Setting Registry Key / Entry :**

- To set registry key or entry, you need to open "Registry Editor".
- To open "Registry Editor" press windows button key + r alphabet key which will open "Run Window" and then type "regedit" and press enter.
- Or Press Windows button key and enter "regedit" at start menu and press enter.
- Now depending upon your OS type whether 32/64 bit follow the corresponding steps.
- Windows 32 bit : go to this location - "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl" and check for "FEATURE_BFCACHE" key.
- Windows 64 bit : go to this location - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl and check for "FEATURE_BFCACHE" key.
- Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present.
- Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

[image]

**Change Settings of Internet Explorer Browser :**

- Click on setting button and select "Internet options".
- On "Internet options" window go to "Security" tab
- Now select "Internet" option and unchecked the "Enable Protected Mode" check box and change the "Security level" to low.
- Now select "Local Intranet" Option and change the "Security level" to low.
- Now select "Trusted Sites" Option and change the "Security level" to low.
  [image: No alt text provided for this image]
- Now click on "Apply" button , a warning pop up may appear click on "OK" button for warning and then on "OK" button on Internet Options window.
  [image: No alt text provided for this image]
- After this restart the browser.

Comment: @Brandon : Let me know if you face any issue with this solution